# Tcolorbox Gradient Problems (with Adobe Acrobat)

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm using tcolorbox to make fancy boxed environments (definitions, remarks, theorems, etc). However, I run into some problems in displaying these in Adobe Acrobat (Version 11.0.20).

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
definitionstyle/.style={%
enhanced,
interior style={top color=magenta!2, bottom color=magenta!15}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[definitionstyle]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox} 

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

which produces an image that bleeds across the page and covers the text below the tcolorbox as well.

[image: MWE_Broken]

On the other hand, if I replace the interior style with `interior style={magenta!15}` then I get the following image:

[image: MWE_Working]

Comment: What is your TeX distribution? Is it up to date?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Well, I'll be damned. There was an update yesterday to tcolorbox which seems to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Hm... I was not aware of that kind of bug and I did not touch or fix anything in that direction for the recent version... But, anyway, I also do not get this error with version 4.10